# How can I replicate email forwarding to and sending from Gmail if my external email provider disabled automatic email forwarding?

Tags: gmail

I have been in academia for over 20 years and adopted Gmail when it was introduced. At every academic institution I've been at, I've received an institution email address. I've always turned on automatic email forwarding from the institution to my Gmail account so that I can manage all email in one consistent location. I use the "send as" feature to send emails from a variety of email addresses/servers. This has worked smoothly for 20 years at several institutions and I do the same at my current job.

But my current institution has abruptly decided to disable automatic email forwarding. This prevents me from using Gmail as my email client as I have been. I will still have IMAP access to my university email account and will be able use a desktop client to download and send email. Is there any way I can connect via IMAP with an always on server and automatically forward the email myself to Gmail in a way that mimics the prior scenario, so that I can continue to use Gmail as my single email client? Or are there other ways to let Gmail be the client for an email address that I only have IMAP routing for?

Comment: I found this similar question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57547/imap-forwarder

Answer (score 0):

### Use an IMAP Synchronisation Tool

---

**Example 1: isync (mbsync):** free IMAP and MailDir mailbox synchronizer
https://isync.sourceforge.io/
A quick look at this tool seems to indicate you can customize the ongoing synchronization in many ways.

**Example 2: imapsync**
https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync
Described as: Email IMAP tool for **syncing**, copying, migrating and archiving email mailboxes between two imap servers, one way, and without duplicates.

Comment: This requires POP, my university only provides IMAP.

Comment: Answer modified